# SQL: Login 'abc' owns one or more databases(s)... Even though I just dropped those roles

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to remove an SQL login with the following commands:

```
USE [myDB]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [abc]
GO
USE [myDB]
GO
DROP USER [abc]
GO
USE [master]
ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [abc]
GO
USE [master]
DROP LOGIN [abc]
GO
```

But SQL returns the following Error:
`Login 'abc' owns one or more database(s). Change the owner of the database(s) before dropping the login.`

There are no other (Non-System-)Databases present on the server and i litterally just dropped the login from role DB_owner - what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users with the `db_owner` role is not the same as being *the* owner of the database.

You should use [`ALTER AUTHORIZATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to give ownership of the database to another principal.

If you get the user's SID then you can query the [`sys.databases`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) catalog view (specifically the `owner_sid` column) to discover which databases they currently own.

Comment: Adding that the database owner (login mapped to the database dbo user) is initially the login that created the database. I've found a good practice is to make a habit of changing the owner immediately after creating a new database to a SQL login specifically for db ownership purposes. `SELECT name, SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) AS Owner FROM sys.databases;` will identify the name of the problem users, with NULL for deleted Windows accounts.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the right direction to investigate... I added this to my Query:
```
if EXISTS (select db.name, db.owner_sid, sp.name  from sys.databases db
join sys.server_principals sp on db.owner_sid = sp.sid
where sp.name = 'abc')
begin
 ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::myDB TO SA
END
```